# Do multiple executable & independent zip files by files number or filesize

Tags: bash, split, zip

I need a shell script that basically does this:

Zip a folder while doing a different zip file every xxx files (or xxx Mo)
I could not use the split method cause I need all file to be independent from each other.
So if I have a folder with 345 files, it will results in

```
zip-1.zip, zip-2.zip, zip-3.zip, zip-4.zip
```

I could not find a solution.

PS, there is no sub-folder.

Comment: Have you tried anything

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
zipsplit -n 1048576 files.zip
```

Creates independent zip files, each 10 MB.

The `-n` option unfortunately reads only bytes - use e.g. http://www.whatsabyte.com/P1/byteconverter.htm

Comment: Thanks.
This was the solution